# Webform File Upload field

Tags: webforms, files, 8

I'm using Drupal 8 with [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

I want to allow users to upload one or several files when filling the form. Is it possible with Drupal 8? May be some additional module required for this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to enable **webform UI**, then set in your **sites/default/settings.php** file the privates files directory path:
`$settings['file_private_path'] = 'sites/default/files/private';` where 'sites/default/files/private' is your privates files directory path. You can choose another directory. And give to this directory the write permission. Then clear all caches. Now you can add files fied in your webform while adding new element. In the popup that appears, typing file, you will see all files type like image, audio, etc. [image: Webform new element form]

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.

Comment: Note that an example of a more secure path would be `'../files'` or `'../private'`

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm on Drupal 9.

Comment: Is this answer still relevant? I'm not getting any file element types.

Comment: I also had to make the file available as an element type within the admin configuration settings section of all webforms (/admin/structure/webform/config/elements)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can allow users to upload files to the webform by adding a new  "managed_file" form element into the "Elements (YAML)":

[image]

This is provided that you have your public and private file paths set, which will otherwise throw a notice telling you to set those up.

Comment: Can I add 'file_upload' field using Webform UI?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution of yaml configuration for images in order to upload a file:

```
picture:
  '#type': image_file
  '#title': Photo
  '#file_extensions': 'gif jpg png svg jpeg'
  '#multiple': True
```

You can install the module Webform UI to do this in the interface...